# QThreads with parameters passing

Tags: qt, qthread

I have a qt gui project, and I have to use threads in it.

Ive been googling alot searching for a way to pass parameters to QThread, and I couldnt find a way.

Does anybody know a way of doing that? Or even use another kind of Threads if QThreads isnt the solution.

Thank you guys!

Comment: google for "qthread the right way" first, then google for "qt slot object parameter passing"

Comment: A possible solution is to use signals and slots

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't need to do anything with a `QThread` other than using it without changes. It won't need any "parameters".

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 2 methods to use QThreads :

1. subclass QThread and reimplement the `run` method
2. subclass QObject and move this object to a QThread using `QObject::moveToThread`

And if you want to *"pass parameters to QThread"*, then it's quiet straightforward with both methods.

1. you can access member variable of your subclass from any methods of your subclass including the reimplemented `run` method.
2. the slot of your worker object, that will be executed in another thread can take as many argument as you want

I recommend you read this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details for more details.

Always keep in mind that QThread itself is not a thread but a class to help managing threads.